# using multiple api calls, after first api others return undefined

Tags: javascript

Everyone does a weather app for api practice so I decided to do something different I'm using Pokeapi to make a small app. I have to call a few different apis to make it work how I want which is being done like this

```
const api = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon";
const apiMoves = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/move";
const apiSpecies = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species"

const searchBox = document.querySelector(".search-box");
searchBox.addEventListener("keypress", setQuery);

function setQuery(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    getResults(searchBox.value);
    searchBox.value = "";
  }
}
function getResults(query) {
  const pokemonData = fetch(`${api}/${query}`)
  .then((data) => {
     return data.json();
  });
  pokemonData.then(displayResults)

  pokemonData.then(data => {
      return fetch(`${apiMoves}/${data.moves[0].move.name}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(move => {
          console.log(move)
      })
  })
  pokemonData.then(data => {
      return fetch(`${apiSpecies}/${query}`)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(species => {
          console.log(species)
      })
  })
}
```

all 3 of the end points are being logged in the console so I can see them. However looking at api call 2 I'm passing info from the first api call to get more info and that logs fine. When I'm trying to display the info from that 2nd api call it just returns undefined but in the console I can see all the endpoints.

the display results looks something like this.

```
function displayResults(pokemon) {
  let name = document.querySelector('h2')
name.innerText = pokemon.name <-- this works.
  let dmg1 = document.querySelector('.dmg1')
dmg1.innerText = pokemon.power <-- this is returning undefined but in the console "power" shows a number.
}
```

I've tried to replace the pokemon.power with move.power but that gives an error saying "move" is not defined.

I'm thinking that I'm simply calling the 2nd and 3rd api wrong? I'm not sure and trying to search for this issue is a bit rough.

any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const pokeApiPrefix = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/';
const apiPokemon = `${pokeApiPrefix}pokemon`;
const apiMoves = `${pokeApiPrefix}move`;
const apiSpecies = `${pokeApiPrefix}pokemon-species`;

const searchBox = document.querySelector('.search-box');
searchBox.addEventListener('keypress', setQuery);

function setQuery(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    getResults(searchBox.value.toLowerCase());
    searchBox.value = '';
  }
}
getResults('Dragonite'.toLowerCase());
function getResults(pokemon) {
   let dmg1 = document.querySelector('.dmg1');
  dmg1.innerText = `Getting results. Please wait...`;
  const pokemonData = fetch(`${apiPokemon}/${pokemon}`)
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(`pokemon data:`, data);
      displayPokemonName(data);
      const moveName = data.moves[0].move.name;
      return fetch(`${apiMoves}/${moveName}`);
    })
    .then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      displayMovePower(data);
      console.log(`move data:`, data);
      return fetch(`${apiSpecies}/${pokemon}`);
    })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(`species data:`, data);
    });
}

// function displayResults(pokemon) {
//   let name = document.querySelector('h2');
//   name.innerText = pokemon.name;
//   let dmg1 = document.querySelector('.dmg1');
//   // I couldn't find 'power' attribute on api results, used id instead
//   // https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#pokemon
//   dmg1.innerText = `#${pokemon.id}`;
// }

function displayPokemonName(pokemon) {
  let name = document.querySelector('h2');
  name.innerText = `Pokemon name: ${pokemon.name}`;
}

function displayMovePower(move) {
  let dmg1 = document.querySelector('.dmg1');
  dmg1.innerText = `Move power: ${move.id}`;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-box" />

<h2></h2>
<div class="dmg1"></div>
```

I've created a snippet, chaining multiple promises and logging every result on the console.
As stated, it seems you are trying to use an attribute 'power', which is not present in the first pokemon api call

Comment: So if you look in the second api object thats returned in the console power is one of the options. the problem is I can't get any of there values from that second api object to display they all returned undefined.

Comment: I see now 'power' as result from the apiMoves. But you're calling displayResults function in the first api call. You still don't have 'power' at that point. Try to see the above link. I've modified it, splitting your displayResultsfunction into two parts and calling them in separate moments when I have the data I need

Comment: Cool so after looking at what you did here I was trying to call information that was ready yet also needed the function to show the info. I feel like I was way off.. Thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 1):

Here this line is not working because you are trying to access the attribute which does not exist in the object.

```
let dmg1 = document.querySelector('.dmg1')
dmg1.innerText = pokemon.power <-- this is returning undefined but in the console "power" shows a number.
```

What might work for you is:

```
dmg1.innerText = pokemon.moves[0].move.name
```

Comment: I know this is confusing let me see if I can explain it pokemon.moves[0].move.name which is going to return "mega-punch" is being used as the search parameter for the second api call.  the second api call will then return some info about "mega-punch" like accuracy, power so on and so forth. I'm now trying to access the the attributes of this returned 2nd api to print out the "power" which is returning undefined